# HTTP Status code for malformed POST body

Tags: rest, post

What status code should a REST service return in response to a POST request containing a malformed / unparseable message body?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**400 Bad Request**

Straight from [the specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html%29):

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

Alternatively, if you need a more specific status you can [create your own 4XX status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1) for whatever API you might be designing.

Answer (score 7):

**400 - Bad Request**

From Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 ([RFC-2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)):

> [400 Bad Request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1)
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

Answer (score -4):

I'd say 412 Precondition Failed

Comment: *412 Precondition Failed: The precondition given in one or more of the request-header fields evaluated to false when it was tested on the server. This response code allows the client to place preconditions on the current resource metainformation (header field data) and thus prevent the requested method from being applied to a resource other than the one intended.*

Comment: Precondition failed relates to failed condition contained in headers; 400 - Bad Request is the proper response in case of malformed entity