# Call external web service using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I am using the following code to call external web service using jquery. In `Chrome`, I am getting this '500 Internal Server Error' and in firefox, it shows `'0'`

I am unable to figure out the problem. Here is my complete code..

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jQuery/1.2.6/jQuery.min.js">   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnCall").click(function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "www.google.com",
                data: "{'ESS123', 'aaaaaa', '', 'abc@hotmail.com', '23424234', '', 0, 100, 1000007, 1, '', 12, '','','', '2013', '', 1, 1000006, 1000033, 100, 1000012, 1000012, 1000001, 1000001, 100, 'caff4eb4fbd6273e37e8a325e19f0991'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('s');
                },
                error: AjaxFailed
            });
        });
    });
    function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
        alert('s');
        //alert(result.d);
    }
    function AjaxFailed(result) {
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }  
</script>

<body>
 <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnCall" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be additional reasons, but your `data` argument does not contain valid JSON. Invalid input is a common reason for 500 Internal Server Errors.

See [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/):

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    'ESS123',    'aaaaa
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

(Hint, strings in JSON must be quoted with `"` characters, and, unlike arrays, objects require key:value pairs not a list of values).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.. Is this the way to do this.. data: {CompanyName: "ESS123", name: "Akhtar", title: "",

Comment: No. Keys in JSON objects must be strings. (And I've no idea what data the web service is expecting for input)

Comment: In this thread answer, he mention the correct way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service

Comment: Btw server should answer with `400 Bad request` in case of bad input better ^^

Comment: @moonwave99 — I think that is when the request does not conform to the HTTP spec. You can have invalid JSON in the body without violating HTTP. Either way, what a server should do isn't all that relevant to the problem when you're working on the client side!

Comment: @MuhammadAkhtar — I'm impressed that he managed to get so many up votes with such an obvious error.

Comment: @Quentin [I think it is a pov matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475157/http-status-code-for-malformed-post-body), imo a malformed request is client responsibility and not server's. Anyway that's not the main question topic :))

Comment: I have follow his answer and now the web service is called. thanks for your help.

Comment: Its working fine in chrome, but when I tried the same one in firefox, I am getting 0 in response, do you have any idea. I am strange.