# Can't use request from Flask library on Python, any ideas?

Tags: python, flask

I have reviewed the code from top to bottom and even though I receive the response and the code 200 on my testing postman environment, it does not print the messages coming from the json on postman neither when executing directly or with a small library file which is only recognizing the type of message (which should not affect the code execution)

I only receive the response but it doesn't print the message

Use the debug method of printing several numbers to see if the error appears and indeed it does not execute beyond line 26 but it is not bad on it's syntax, I also tried if flask was installed and running and yes, I access --help and --version of flask without problem, I'm I missing something?

```
from flask import Flask, request
import util
import whatsappservice

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/welcome', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "welcome developer"

@app.route('/whatsapp', methods=['GET'])
def VerifyToken():
        
        accessToken = "15625885266775"
        token = request.args.get("hub.verify_token")
        challenge = request.args.get("hub.challenge")
        
        if token != None and challenge != None and token == accessToken:
            return challenge
        else:
            return "", 400


@app.route('/whatsapp', methods=['POST'])
def ReceivedMessage():
    try:
        print("1")
        body = request.get_json ()
        print("2")
        entry = (body["entry"]) [0]
        print("3")
        changes = (entry["changes"]) [0]
        print("4")
        value = changes ["value"]
        print("5")
        message = (value["messages"]) [0]
        print("6")
        number = message ["from"]
        print("7")

        text = util.GetTextUser(message)
        print("8")
        GenerateMessage(text, number)
        print("9")
        print (text)
        print("10")
```

[image: code]

It should show a text from json on postman environment
[image]

Comment: in postman, you are sending Text.
(x) raw ( ) binary ( ) GraphQL. Text <--- Change this to JSON

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the request object does not contain a valid JSON object.

The [`Request.get_json()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=get_json#flask.Request.get_json) method tries to parse the request body as a JSON object and returns it. If the request body is not in valid JSON format, the method raises a `BadRequest` exception, which will cause the code to stop executing beyond that point.

Since your code was wrapped in a `try` block, any raised exceptions would be caught and the execution path would go into your `except` block instead. It appears as though from the screenshot that you return a string in both blocks.

According to HTTP conventions though, if the request body is malformed, you should not just return a string ([which by default](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=view#flask.Flask.make_response), makes a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response). Instead, respond with a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` as answered in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475157/http-status-code-for-malformed-post-body).

You can try this pattern:

```
@app.route('/whatsapp', methods=['POST'])
def ReceivedMessage():
    try:
        body = request.get_json()
        entry = body["entry"][0]
        changes = entry["changes"][0]
        value = changes["value"]
        message = value["messages"][0]
        number = message["from"]
        text = util.GetTextUser(message)
        GenerateMessage(text, number)
        return "Message received"
    except BadRequest:
        return "Invalid request payload", 400
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return "Invalid request structure", 400
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An error occurred: {e}", 500
```

Alternatively, you can set a default [error handler](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/errorhandling/?highlight=return#error-handlers) as well:

```
import werkzeug

@app.errorhandler(werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest)
def handle_bad_request(e):
    return "Invalid request payload", 400
```